# 20amp breaker keeps tripping

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker

I have a 20 amp type QO GFCI circuit breaker (12 GU wire) that is tripping under load. My home is about 5 years old and the breaker provides power to half of the kitchen outlets and part of the dining room. The breaker just started tripping few weeks ago. We use a air fryer on this circuit and it trips about a minute after it has been on. I tested the amps while on and it reads 12.5 max. I’ve tested a different appliance on the circuit with the same results. Additionally, I tested the air fryer on a different 15 amp circuit, no issues. Do I have a bad breaker? If not, what else could be the issue? Thank you[image]!

Comment: I rechecked the wiring and I made a mistake on identifying the correct wire. It is actually a 12 GU. Apologies!

Comment: Are you absolutely sure there is nothing on the circuit but the 12.5A/1500W heating appliance?  **If you plug the appliance into the *other* kitchen receptacle circuit, does it trip *that* GFCI?**

Comment: Yes, if you plug the appliance into a different GFCI circuit, does *that* GFCI trip?

Answer (score 1):

GFCI breakers are prone to fail earlier than traditional breakers. I would swap the breaker with another functioning GFCI breaker from the electrical panel to see if the problem follows the breaker or continues on the existing circuit.

Comment: I don't like GFCI breakers. Can somebody tell me the (economic) logic of using a $40 breaker instead of a $5 breaker and a $15 receptacle? Other than creating the need to call an electrician to troubleshoot a simple gfci failure.

Comment: $20 bucks more to the company, likely for the same $10 worth of parts. I certainly take the "first device is a GFCI" approach to this issue personally. Non-economically, I guess it means you'll find the GFCI trip and the overload trip in the same place. And you don't have to live with the horror of having a Decora device if you have some attachment to the appearance of "olde-fashioned outlets with little rounded faces." I suppose some electricians installing them might appreciate the built in service calls...

Comment: @ nosparksplease, this would make a good question but it is off topic here. Code requires GFCI or AFCI breakers in almost every circuit today. I disagree with some reasoning as they never recalled FPE stablock panels and they have been a cause of many fires. I have heard bad things about zinsco but not experienced the issues that others have with the buss bars as I always have used deox on all aluminum clamps and fitting since just after getting my license in the 70’s

Comment: @NoSparksPlease Because you're thinking of idealized situations where exactly one recep placement can protect the whole circuit.  Lots of circuits are not like that, now you're into 2+ receps and all that cost savings just vaporized.   Also if you need an electrician to troubleshoot a simple GFCI failure, well, don't quit your day job :)

Comment: Just finished up wiring up a home for my son (new build).  Just about all circuits required AFCI breakers at the panel. Then GFCI in places like kitchen and bathrooms, etc. We decided to go with dual function (AFCI & GFCI breakers) because the cost diff between AFCI and "dufies" was so small, then we didn't need GFCI recps.  Can be inconvenient to have to go to main panel to reset a GFI trip, but my son was OK with that.   We'll see.  BTW, when with Square D QO plug on neutral panel & breakers, makes for a very clean panel:  No pigtails!

Comment: One more thing:  I found dual function receps, (much less $$$) but here in Washington st. they don't allow them in new construction, only remodels.

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson dual function recepts are frickin useless. The whole point of AFCI is to protect the wire in the walls, and that only works 2 places: at the service panel, or in a steel junction box connected via EMT within 2' of the panel.  I do that one all the time because I'm not willing to pay ??? for a Pushmatic AFCI/GFCI breaker.

Comment: @NoSparksPlease
In regions with rodents, especially martens, (or less talented inhabitants drilling holes into walls) GFCIs in the 1st (main) panel could be useful to save lifes and values. If the walls are made out of wood, a fire could start, if the cable insulation is bitten off and moisture/saliva or dirt makes a connection resulting in a current below the circuit breaker rating. 100W would be enough. There is a high probability that the neighboring PE wire would be also damaged (if not anyway) taking some current and the GFCI interrupts the power before a big fire sets in.

Comment: Harper, you are going to be upset when the 2020 code kicks in.  From what I understand of the new code, virtually EVERYTHING in the house must be GFCI protected, including things like furnaces, dryers, water heaters, ranges.

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson -- 2020 doesn't change what *places* GFCI protection is required, it just makes it so that it no longer only applies to 15A and 20A circuits in those same places.